# guaranteeing print dimensions / layout for a dynamically generated html page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, printing

I have a page that I need to design in PhP/Html/Java/CSS that has to be printed out Exactly to a certain size on the clients printer. The printer uses labels (similar to fedex/ups) that have multiple parts, and the design is made so that the label, when seperated into its parts, has certain data on each.

Any advice on the exact way to guarantee my page prints out properly on say a 5x7 label?

I have full control of the design, but all css must be done in-line.

The device that prints it will not scale anything. Once designed, this page's only purpose is to be printed on this device. Usability, design, all of that is unimportant as long as it prints this label correctly on this printer. The printer may be hooked up to multiple different PC's, or multiple PC's may be printing this page to the same printer/same model printers.

is there any easy way other than "guess and check"?

Comment: Did you really mean [tag:java], or do you mean [tag:javascript]? They're very different.

Comment: Output printed will be affected by Print settings as well. You can't control all settings in CSS.

Comment: Javascript; I am starting to design this page and just trying to discover the best way to design this page to be printed exactly onto a specific size paper (IE 4x8.5)

Comment: Don't print from the browser. Produce a PDF or EPS document and print that

Comment: how would I determine the exact settings for a PDF to guarantee that it is not scaled? the content of the page has barcodes that if scaled at all outside of the PhP generation, will not read.

Comment: @user1298883, I have yet to see a barcode that can't be read if it is scaled to reasonable levels.  Besides, you will have far more predictable printing size with PDF than you will web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHP to output a PDF file, then print that.  The layout, fonts, etc. in a PDF file will be much more consistent when printed from different locations compared to CSS.

I made scan-able name badges on 2 col x 6 row "sticker paper" for a conference this way.  They had 3 different laptops printing badges at the checkin, worked out great.

http://php.net/pdf

Answer (score 2):

You may have to go for the trial and error approach if you don't want to generate a PDF.

There is a CSS rule that you may find useful if you're printing to multiple pages. The following will insert a page break after every `.labelset`.

```
<style>
@media print
{
    .labelset { page-break-after:always; }
}
</style>
```

So with this just make sure a set of labels prints to 1 page safely given the default margin of the browser that the client will use.